# Powershell : Exception de HRESULT : 0x80131047 with class creation

Tags: powershell, class

I'm having some trouble with basic things.
I'd like to create a class with Powershell.

For this, I have created a .PS1 file.

here, my file's content :

```
Class WindchillSession {

    [string]$serverName
    [int]$port
    [string]$userID
    [string]$userPassword   
}
```

When I launch my PS1 script, with a powershell window I have [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSWzE.png)

```
Le nom ou le code base de l'assembly donné n'est pas valide. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80131047)
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ .\WindChill_API.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException
```

I have no idea of the error's reason , and you ?
I haven't founded anything on internet about problem with class creation on Powershell and 0x80131047 error ( but I find frequently this code, but for C# and not about classes)

By advance, thank you for your answers

Comment: What is your powershell version?

Comment: @Abdul :  PSVersion : 5.1.19041.906

Comment: Someone know, why we can't say "Hi", or "Hello" at the post beginning ? My original post was edited :-(

Comment: Editing out the "fluff" from posts is standard operating procedure around here. It's nothing personal and serves to keep things focused on the issue at hand. For further reading see [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) and [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)